# How to get the id of a course to post to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add posts but the post controller is unable to get the id of the course via `params[:id]`.

This is the create method in my post controller:

```
def create
 @coursePost = CoursePost.new(post_params)
 @coursePost.course_id = params[:id]
 if (@coursePost.save)
  redirect_to "/courses"
 end
end
```

This form  gets the text field data from the respective courses show page:

```
<%= form_for(@newPost) do |f| %>
 <div class= "field">
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
 </div>
 <div class= "field">
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
 </div>
 <div class= "actions">
  <%= f.submit "Post!" %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the show method in the courses controller:

```
def show
 @posts = CoursePost.all.where("course_id = ?", params[:id])
 @newPost = CoursePost.new
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the `course_id` for the course like the id params you're sending, but in your form you're not sending any id, just `title` and `content`.

So you could try adding the `course_id` with any input to be able to receive it and the in your controller assign it to your `@coursePost` as the `params[:course_id]`, like:

In your view:

```
<%= form_for(@newPost) do |f| %>
  <div class= "field">
    <%= f.text_field :course_id %>
  </div>
  <div class= "field">
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  ...
```

In your controller:

```
@coursePost.course_id = params[:course_id]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your speedy response, i managed to fix it thanks to you.

Comment: Thanks but i did this so it adds it to the current course                             
<%= hidden_field_tag(:course_id, @course.id) %> and then just did params [:course_id]

Comment: That's great, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I worked out a similar project. Below is my code for your reference.

```
def create
  @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
  @coursePost = CoursePost.new(post_params)
  @coursePost.course = @course
  @coursePost.user = current_user
  if @coursePost.save
     redirect_to course_path(@course)
  else
     render :new
  end
end

private
def post_params
    params.require(:coursePost).permit(:content)
end
```

Here is the show method in the courses controller

```
def show
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  @coursePosts = @course.coursePosts
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is handled for you if you follow the Rails recommendations:

```
# routes
resources :courses do
  resources :posts
end

# posts controller
def new
  @course = Course.find(params[:course_id]
  @post = @course.posts.new
end

def create
  @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
  @post = @course.posts.new(post_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  # ...
end

# form
form_for [@course, @post] do |f|
  # ...
end
```